# How do i know when my app is going to kill

Tags: android

I am working on Gps based application which runs all the time in background. But in extreme low memory case(or when i open many apps) my app is killed by the android system.

I want to relaunch my app when it is killed by android system.I google it for this but don't get any solution.Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Android apps are going to kill? :-O  I'm never buying this gadget!

Comment: lol +1 for you and the very badly chosen title... :D

Answer (score 2):

Have you done your GPS logic inside a service? The service is one of the last things that will be killed and mostly because it has to be killed to free needed memory.

Maybe your service should create a notification so the user is informed and can restart the app by hand by clicking the notification...

Comment: thanks to reply, no i did the logic in my activity. Everything is wokring fine. The thing that i want to know is "which method is called when your app is killed". I tried onLowMemory() but it is not called in that case..

Comment: the very last method called when your app is going to be stopped is `onDestroy()` I am not sure if this is still the case when a task manager app kills your app.

Comment: hi friends i did this using alarm service. Thanks to share your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at this [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#actlife) flowchart? In the case where other applications need memory, onPause() is the last guaranteed thing that happens before your app is stopped or killed. So that is where you would need a notification (as @WarrenFaith says) or another mechanism which could potentially revive your app or at least ping the user to revive it.

Answer (score 1):

I think [startForeground()][1] is what you are looking for. Android won't kill your service, so you don't have to worry about restarting it.

Good luck
Tom

[1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int, android.app.Notification)

Answer (score 0):

You could try launching a new instance of the app when the onDestroy() function is called. For example:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Thisclass.this, Thisclass.class);
    Thisclass.this.startActivity(intent);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: bad idea! this could create an infinite loop!

Comment: What if he really wants to end the app! This will need a task manager to end it!

Comment: Oh yeah, that's true, sorry! :)
This could be avoided with setting a boolean when the user wants to exit and checking that in that method and possibly bypassing the relaunch. Services would seem like a better solution as WarrenFaith mentions below.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can make use of intents, send a token out to another listener when this application is being killed by android, so that the other serivce can initiate this activity.

Though I cannot see how this will not be a loop. The way you end your app is very similar to the way android ends your app! so I am pretty sure it will be looping infinitely when you try to end the app, behaving very much like a malware!